# Get timestamps of censored words from Azure Speech to Text Services using Python

Tags: python, azure, speech-to-text, azure-cognitive-services

How can I get the offset and duration of the censored words (profanity) in an Audio file with Azure Speech to Text Services using Python?
I can see that the swearing words in the converted text are starred and have the same length as the spoken words. 
I wanted to get the timestamp at which the swearing words are spoken so that I can use the information to take actions like muting the Audio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to request for word-level timestamp in your recognition. You can find how with this answer: [How to get Word Level Timestamps using Azure Speech to Text and the Python SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56842391/how-to-get-word-level-timestamps-using-azure-speech-to-text-and-the-python-sdk)

In a few words, you have to use `speech_config.request_word_level_timestamps()`

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!